# Failed LockRect of IDirect3DSurface9

Tags: c++, locking, directx, video-capture

I have hooked Present method of the IDirect3DDevice9 interface, and I want to be able to start video capturing.

Taking a screenshoot like this work

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState('O') & 1) {
    pDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface((rect.right - rect.left),(rect.bottom - rect.top),D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8,D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM,&back_buffer, NULL);
    pDevice->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &back_buffer);
    D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile(L"C:\\screenshot.bmp", D3DXIFF_BMP, back_buffer, 0, NULL );

    IDirect3DSurface9_Release(back_buffer);
}
```

I seem to fail to lock the surface.

```
HRESULT APIENTRY hook_Present(IDirect3DDevice9* pDevice, const RECT* pSourceRect,const RECT* pDestRect, HWND hDestWindowOverride,const RGNDATA* pDirtyRegion) {
    IDirect3DSurface9*back_buffer;
    D3DDEVICE_CREATION_PARAMETERS cparams;
    RECT rect;
    pDevice->GetCreationParameters(&cparams);
    GetClientRect(cparams.hFocusWindow, &rect);
    if (GetAsyncKeyState('R') & 1) {
        if(dx9Capturing == 0) {
            //Create the AVI file
            // etc code
            dx9Capturing = 1
        }
        else if(dx9Capturing == 1) dx9Capturing = 2; // stop capturing
    }

    if(dx9Capturing == 1) {
        // Capture the current frame
        pDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface((rect.right - rect.left),(rect.bottom - rect.top),D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8,D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM,&back_buffer, NULL);
        pDevice->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &back_buffer);
        D3DLOCKED_RECT  lockedRect;
        if(FAILED(back_buffer->LockRect(&lockedRect,&rect,D3DLOCK_READONLY))) {
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed locking the back buffer!", "Error", MB_OK);
            return orig_Present(pDevice, pSourceRect, pDestRect, hDestWindowOverride, pDirtyRegion);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<rect.bottom;i++)
            {
                memcpy((BYTE*)pBits+(rect.bottom-i-1)*rect.right*BITSPERPIXEL/8,(BYTE*)lockedRect.pBits+i*lockedRect.Pitch,rect.right*BITSPERPIXEL/8);
            }
        back_buffer->UnlockRect();
        pAviFile->AddNewFrame(rect.right,rect.bottom,pBits);
    }

    return orig_Present(pDevice, pSourceRect, pDestRect, hDestWindowOverride, pDirtyRegion);
}
```

Comment: I also fail when I call getDesc on a surface

Comment: I also cant pDevice->GetFrontBufferData(0, offscreen_surface)), GetFrontBufferData fails...

Comment: Also i can't use GetAdapterDisplayMode in Present, thats why I use GetCreationParameters

Comment: What is the returned HRESULT value when those API calls fail?

Comment: 0x8876086C(D3DERR_INVALIDCALL)

Comment: You should post this question in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/  or gamedev.net. It has been ages I have not gone through D3D 9 APIs so don't remember much.

Answer (score 0):

`D3DERR_INVALIDCALL` means the size of your back buffer is not equal to the resolution of monitor. for example when you want to capture a monitor with following resolution(1920 * 1080), the back buffer of directX9 must be create with the same size.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Might be better as a comment